# Python multiprocessing import issues without error

Tags: python, windows, import, multiprocessing

I have the following scripts:

main.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
#import my_mod as mm

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

my_mod.py

```
def test():
    return
```

This works but when I uncomment line 2 in main.py the execution of the script just hangs up without giving me any error. What could be the cause of this mysterious behaviour? I don't have import errors with other modules and this seems to be somehow related to the multiprocessing module. I am on Windows 7 using Anaconda version 4.3.17.

Comment: are you having an __inti__.py blank file in the directory??

Comment: No this is not the case... Did you try to run the code? Do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: You're probably not showing the full code in module `my_mod`

Comment: Sure I do. There is no more code in this module since it is a minimal example. All the code was copy-pasted from the files as they are.

Comment: For some reason the multiprocessing module does not seem to work on my system. As a workaround I'll use the _thread module which seems to work.

Comment: If it's really an issue with your `multiprocessing` module, maybe you could try `concurrent.futures`. It still uses multiprocessing under the hood, but maybe its abstractions can make it work somehow? At least it might be worth a try. :-\ https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: Thanks for the link. Their tutorial code works on my system: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example But in the meantime there is no need for me any more to use another module since _thread suits my needs. But thank you anyways!

Comment: You should use `threading`. The `_thread` module is low level and normally shouldn't be used. Bear in mind that CPython's GIL prevents multiple threads from using the interpreter at the same time, so CPU bound problems won't see improvement from threading and may even see degraded performance as threads compete for access. In CPython, threads are useful for I/O bound problems.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I was not aware of the high-/low-level aspect. I'll check out the module.